# How to clone typing to every input from the first box with jquery on checkbox checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to clone/duplicate the typing of the first input of each column in to the child boxes of the same class/id.

For example, there're 5 columns of data. Each column has its own class and specific ids. Once I start typing on the top input of each column and the checkbox checked. The following/child inputs of that column start typing the same stroke.

**JS**

```
var $input1 = $(document).find('input[id^="box"]').filter(':visible:first'); //find the first input begins with *box or other same id???
$($input1).keypress(function() { //duplicate the first box typing
  var $this = $(this);
  window.setTimeout(function() { //delay a bit
    if ($('#cloneAll').is(':checked')) { //if checkbox empty
      $('*[id^="box"]').val($this.val()).attr('readonly', true); //clone all inputs and set them readonly
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

**html**

```
 1.<input type="text" value="" id="box1" /><label><input type="checkbox" id="cloneAll" />clone all</label>
<br /> 2.<input type="text" value="" id="box2" />
<br /> 3.<input type="text" value="" id="box3" />
<br /> 4.<input type="text" value="" id="box4" />
<br /> 5.<input type="text" value="" id="box5" />
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> 100.<input type="text" value="" id="box100" /><br />
```

The questions are:

1. How to find the first input of each set of class/id and set it as a prototype?
2. How to continue typing the following input without stuck when a checkbox checked?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/be9br09j/1/) or

```js
var $input1 = $(document).find('input[id^="box"]').filter(':visible:first'); //find the first input begins with *box or other same id???
$($input1).keypress(function() { //duplicate the first box typing
  var $this = $(this);
  window.setTimeout(function() { //delay a bit
    if ($('#cloneAll').is(':checked')) { //if checkbox empty
      $('*[id^="box"]').val($this.val()).attr('readonly', true); //clone all inputs and set them readonly
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1.
<input type="text" value="" id="box1" />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cloneAll" />clone all</label>
<br /> 2.
<input type="text" value="" id="box2" />
<br /> 3.
<input type="text" value="" id="box3" />
<br /> 4.
<input type="text" value="" id="box4" />
<br /> 5.
<input type="text" value="" id="box5" />
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> 100.
<input type="text" value="" id="box100" />
<br />
```

Comment: You are setting all the boxes to readonly. That's why you can't keep typing

Comment: Because I want it to follow the typing of the `first` input if its id. So how to exclude it then?

Comment: You already have the first box as a variable so just add `$input1.attr('readonly', false);` after the line that sets all the boxes to readonly

Comment: ok it's working! => http://jsfiddle.net/be9br09j/2/

Comment: Also, you don't need the parentheses around `$input1` on your second line. It can just be `$input1.keypress(function() {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line in your code is setting **all** the input boxes to readonly and preventing you from typing in the first box as well.

```
$('*[id^="box"]').val($this.val()).attr('readonly', true); //clone all inputs and set them readonly
```

If you add this line beneath it, it will allow you to continue typing in the first box.

```
$input1.attr('readonly', false);
```

**Updated Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/be9br09j/2/

**Updated Snippet**

```js
var $input1 = $(document).find('input[id^="box"]').filter(':visible:first'); //find the first input begins with *box or other same id???
$($input1).keypress(function() { //duplicate the first box typing
  var $this = $(this);
  window.setTimeout(function() { //delay a bit
    if ($('#cloneAll').is(':checked')) { //if checkbox empty
      $('*[id^="box"]').val($this.val()).attr('readonly', true); //clone all inputs and set them readonly
      $input1.attr('readonly', false);
    }
  }, 0);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1.
<input type="text" value="" id="box1" />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cloneAll" />clone all</label>
<br /> 2.
<input type="text" value="" id="box2" />
<br /> 3.
<input type="text" value="" id="box3" />
<br /> 4.
<input type="text" value="" id="box4" />
<br /> 5.
<input type="text" value="" id="box5" />
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> 100.
<input type="text" value="" id="box100" />
<br />
```

Comment: May I ask a lil bit more? What if there're more than 1 set of these input and I don't want to change the code everytime I want to clone it.What is the best way to tell the program to follow the typing from?

Comment: Asking questions in the comments is generally discouraged. Please ask a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and post the link here and I'll try to help.

Comment: I got a new thread here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/46159961/1620626. Please give me a hand (-/\-)