# How to clone typing to every input from the first box with jquery on checkbox checked (dynamically)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Referring to the solution of https://stackoverflow.com/a/46159513/1620626 with a big help from @osdavison.

Now I want the script to find it's child `class` or `id` without predefined it. All I thinking now is making a `function`. So I'd hope to do this.

**JS**

```
function cloneAllz(chkBoxID, clsName) {
  alert(chkBoxID + '/' + clsName);//test value
  var $input1 = $(document).find('#' + clsName).filter(':visible:first'); //find the first input begins with *box or other same id???
  $input1.keypress(function() { //duplicate the first box typing
    var $this = $(this);
    window.setTimeout(function() { //delay a bit
      if ($('#' + chkBoxID).is(':checked')) { //if checkbox empty
        $('*[id^="' + clsName + '"]').val($this.val()).attr('readonly', true); //clone all inputs and set them readonly
        $input1.attr('readonly', false);
      }
    }, 0);
  });
}
```

**HTML**

```
 1.
<input type="text" value="" id="box1" />
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="cloneAll" onChange="cloneAllz('cloneAll','box')" />clone all</label>
<br /> 2.
<input type="text" value="" id="box2" />
<br /> 3.
<input type="text" value="" id="box3" />
<br /> 4.
<input type="text" value="" id="box4" />
<br /> 5.
<input type="text" value="" id="box5" />
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> .
<br /> 100.
<input type="text" value="" id="box100" />
<br />
```

All I got from the console is `Uncaught ReferenceError: cloneAllz is not defined`

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/be9br09j/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly your fiddle is using jQuery 1.5.2 which is *very* outdated. You should update that ASAP.

Secondly you should use unobtrusive event handlers instead of event attributes in the HTML.

To fix your actual problem you can hook to the `input` event of the first `input`. Within that event handler you can inspect to see if the checkbox is checked, and if so se the `val()` of all other inputs to match that of the current one. Using this method will massively simplify your code which currently seems a little over-complicated. Try this:

```js
$('.container .master').on('input', function() {
  var $container = $(this).closest('.container');
  if ($container.find('.cloneAll').is(':checked'))
    $container.find('input:not(.master)').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  1. <input type="text" value="" class="master" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cloneAll" />
    clone all
  </label><br /> 

  2. <input type="text" value="" id="box2" /><br /> 
  3. <input type="text" value="" id="box3" /><br /> 
  4. <input type="text" value="" id="box4" /><br /> 
  5. <input type="text" value="" id="box5" /><br /> 
  .<br /> .<br /> .<br /> 
  100. <input type="text" value="" id="box100" />
</div><br /><br />

<div class="container">
  1. <input type="text" value="" class="master" />
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" class="cloneAll" />
    clone all
  </label><br /> 

  2. <input type="text" value="" id="box2" /><br /> 
  3. <input type="text" value="" id="box3" /><br /> 
  4. <input type="text" value="" id="box4" /><br /> 
  5. <input type="text" value="" id="box5" /><br /> 
  .<br /> .<br /> .<br /> 
  100. <input type="text" value="" id="box100" />
</div>
```

Comment: What if there're more than 1 set of these inputs? In my work here. There're 10 rows of data. Each row has 4 inputs. I want to change the whole column with a checkbox and change them at once. That's why I keep finding the way to work it dynamically.

Comment: In which case, wrap each set of elements in a containing element, such as a `div` and use DOM traversal to only effect elements within the current set

Comment: So when there's another container. I just create another set of code and rename `.container2` to use with?

Comment: No, they should all be named `container` because the code finds the closest element with class `container` in the DOM hierarchy and uses that one

Comment: Now I'm adapted the way data show. From purely input stack into table. I named the class of each `td`, for example `td class="col1"`. And I replace the script like `$('.col1 .master').on('input', function() {`. But it's not working, I'm updating fiddle...

Comment: Two issues there; firstly `.cde` is not far enough up the tree to use with `closest()`, you need to go back to the `tr`. Secondly, as you've only got a single checkbox in the table, you don't need to use `find()` there and can just select it directly. Here's a fixed fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7h68yz0p/2/

Answer (score 0):

After a night I head ached. This noon I come up with the working code. Thanks to those efforts and google. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gax7562s/)

```js
$(document).on('change', $('.clone'), function(el) {
  var $this = $(el.target);
  var $clss = $(el.target).attr('value'); //target class name
  var $master = $('.prdEdt').find('td.' + $clss + ' input[type="text"]').filter(':visible:first');
  var $tdVal = $('td.' + $clss + '>input[type="text"]');

  if ($this.is(':checked')) {
    $($tdVal).attr('readonly', 'true'); //set child readonly
    $master.attr('readonly', false); //exclude 1st input

    $master.on('input', function() {
      $($tdVal).val($(this).val());
      $tdVal.each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('id') + '/' + $(this).val());
        //call ajax
      });
    })
  } else {
    console.log('unchecked');
    $($tdVal).removeAttr('readonly');
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped prdEdt">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Code
      <label class="pull-right label label-default">
        <input type="checkbox" class="clone" value='cde' /> <em class="fa fa-clone"></em></label>
    </th>
    <th>Title
      <label class="pull-right label label-default">
        <input type="checkbox" class="clone" value="tt_en"  /> <em class="fa fa-clone"></em></label>
    </th>
    <th>Cost</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00067</td>
    <td class="cde">
      <input type="text" name="prd_cde" id="prd_cde|67" class="form-control" value="3000009" />
    </td>
    <td class="tt_en">
      <input type="text" name="prd_title_en" id="prd_title_en|67" class="form-control" value="TRANSFER" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="prd_cost" id="prd_cost|67" class="form-control" value="800" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>00068</td>
    <td class="cde">
      <input type="text" name="prd_cde" id="prd_cde|68" class="form-control " value="3000009" />
    </td>
    <td class="tt_en">
      <input type="text" name="prd_title_en" id="prd_title_en|68" class="form-control " value="TRANSFER" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="number" name="prd_cost" id="prd_cost|68" class="form-control" value="600" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```